# careers: not interested in job offers means can't answer messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I had a message from careers.stackoverflow.com. Having recently accepted another job I went to change my status to no longer actively looking. At that point I could no longer view my messages, and so couldn't reply to tell the asker that I was no longer actively looking, which seems a bit rude.

I assume this is a bug? The standard email message both asks me to reply to the message and update my status if no longer appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

This has been updated so you can now view/respond to/interact with/etc your messages when you are set to be not searchable.